# google translate unknown words

Tags: google-translate

I'm using Google translate from hebrew to english, this way:
    https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=" + DWord + "&target=en&format=text&source=iw&key=

But when the word I sent is unknown it is returning me the phonetics in english for that word. In that case I don't want to get that and pay for that, I'll prefer to get an error or null and not to be charged fot that, since there was no actual translation, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try a different translator like : http://translate.reference.com